# Combining two subnets with same default gateway

Tags: networking, subnet, gateway

This is the current situation:

- Subnet 1: 192.168.1.x (255.255.255.0) with default gateway on 192.168.1.1
- Subnet 2: 192.168.90.x (255.255.255.0) without any gateway (no internet access) -> all devices use static IP addresses

I would like to combine these two subnets. I already tried to change the subnet of the default gateway to 255.255.128.0 and it actually worked but I ran into internet connection issues even though everything in the LAN worked fine. My guess here is that my gateway isn't capable of handling that many subnets. So I changed it back to the situation above.

Is there any other way to combine these two subnets? I sadly can't change the IP addresses of the two subnets.

Comment: What are you using as your gateway? A router, server, desktop, switch, IP over Avian Carrier?

Comment: Router with Firewall included

Answer (score 3):

You have a few obvious choices.

**Choice 1**: Add a link (VLAN trunk or separate physical interface) to your router with an address in the 192.168.90.0/24 subnet. Config your router's address on that interface to be 192.168.90.1, and assign that as the gateway to your clients in 192.168.90.0/24.

**Choice 2**: Change the subnet mask of your 192.168.1.0/24 subnet to 255.255.128.0 (/17).  This will need to be changed on absolutely everything on the network; Router, static routes, firewall rules, clients, etc etc.  The reason it didn't work for you before is because some of the devices weren't changed.

It will only be a single subnet at that point.  There's no reason a router wouldn't be able to handle a defined /17, unless it's some consumer-grade home router with restrictions to predefined blocks.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is really helpful! I will look into both options!

Answer (score -1):

The solution for you depends on your specific network configuration, and the capabilities of the equipment that you have in your environment.  If your switches can handle VLANS, then using a VLAN trunk to help route the traffic is a solid method to use.

Consider the possibility of adding an additional IP address to the internal interface on your router (If it lets you), make that IP address 192.168.90.1, and point your computers on the 192.168.90.1 subnet to your new default gateway.  The .90 network should then be able to access the .1 network and vice versa.  You can have a single interface with multiple IP addresses.